$H^0(X;G)\approx\mathrm{Hom}\left(H_0(X),G\right)$
I totally understand that the universal coefficient theorem reduces to an isomorphism $H^0(X;G)\approx\mathrm{Hom}\left(H_0(X),G\right)$ because when $n=0$ there is no $\mathrm{Ext}$ term. However, I'm confused by seeing this fact directly from definitions.
Since singular $0$-simplices are points of $X$, a cochain in $C^0(X;G)$ is an arbitrary function $\varphi:X\rightarrow G$. For this to be a cocycle means that for each singular $1$-simplex $\sigma:[v_0,v_1]\rightarrow X$, we have $$\delta\varphi(\sigma)=\varphi(\partial\sigma)=\varphi\left(\sigma(v_1)\right)-\varphi\left(\sigma(v_0)\right)=0.$$
This is equivalent to saying that $\varphi$ is constant on path components of $X$.
Thus, shouldn't $H^0(X;G)=\mathrm{Ker}\ \delta/\mathrm{Im}\ \delta$ be all the constant functions from path-components of $X$ to $G$? But in fact, they are not necessarily constant. Where did I go wrong?

You have shown that $H^0(X,G)$ are the locally constant functions on X: they are constant on each connected component. But if $X$ is the union of two components $Y$ and $Z$, such a map can have value $a$ on $Y$, and $b$ on $Z$. In other words, these are functions $\pi_0(X) \rightarrow G$ (not necessarily the constant ones), inducing $H_0(X) \rightarrow G$. I hope I understood your issue correctly !

@FrançoisGatine Very helpful! Thanks!
